# setTranslation not working layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

This is code for setTranslation . But transation not working. This code is calling out side activity . Any problem with this. Same code working perfectly in an activity.

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
      params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(myView, params);

    lockParent  =   myView.findViewById(R.id.lockParent);
    lockParent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(arg1.getAction());
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                System.out.println("down");
                downX = arg1.getRawX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                System.out.println("move");
                deltaX = arg1.getRawX() - downX;
                lockParent.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                break;                  
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you call it? Where do you call it? What happens when you call it? Do you get any error? Maybe a crash? Have you checked Logcat?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Am calling this from a service. translation values are getting correctly but translation is not happening.

Comment: any help about this /

Answer (score 0):

Move everything in your activity_home into FrameLayout and translate content inside that layout.

Suppose your activity_home layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lockParent>
...

<RelativeLayout>
```

Modified activity_home layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lockParent>
    ...

    <RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout>
```